# eventDrop programmatically in FullCalendar jquery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have functional Full Calendar page and I want to move an event on **another hour of the day**. What I m trying is to use the **$.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);** but while the title is changing successfully the new time of the event cannot configured properly (is not changing).

I tried to set the time manually to the event like this:

```
 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getCalendar');
 event._start = calendar.moment(new Date('2015','04','05','23','00','00'));
```

or

```
event._start = $.fullCalendar.moment(new Date('2015','04','05','23','00','00'));
```

But the event still is on the same position with the time unchanged.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use `event.start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this fragment for code. Use `event.start` Instead of `event._start`

```
event.start = $.fullCalendar.moment('2014-05-01'); 
//change OR add date and time accordingly
```

Comment: When I m using this code then the event disappears but with no console errors.